# Socket Programming between Django REST API, VUE and Scrapy

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-rest-framework, scrapy

Write now my code is able to successfully send a post request to the Django REST API which in result triggers the spider respectively and stores its output to the database successfully. For this cause I am using scrapyd API as you can see in the below code snippet

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
def crawlRottenTomatoes(request):
    print("in crawl tottentomatoes method")
    url = request.data["url"]

    if not url:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Missing  args'})

    if not is_valid_url(url):
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'URL is invalid'})
    domain = urlparse(url).netloc
    msg_dic = {}
    try:
        scrapyd.schedule(project="movie_spider", spider="rottentomatoes", url=url, domain=domain)
        msg_dic['msg'] = "Spider RottenTomatoes for given url is up and running"
    except Exception as e:
        print("exception")
        msg_dic['error'] = "Error running spider for RottenTomatoes"
    return JsonResponse(msg_dic, safe=False)
```

But now what I want. Is to have some kind of response back from the scrapyd when it's done crawling and parsing the website/channel for that I came across the WebSockets. I tried to use WebSockets but the problem is scrapyd is a demon itself. I am not really able to send a message to the WebSocket client from the scrappy. Does anyone have any idea of how do to do or can share some resources which can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the API reference, it seems the only way to get the status of a scrapyd job is via `listjobs` https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#listjobs-json and looking for your job's `id` in the list.

Another option is to monitor scrapyd's log file. Or you could also try to add this feature to https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd where it would send an http request after it's done with a job.